# How to perform query string based API call in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angualr js. I have found a very useful article about how to connect to API and use their information to show into our app using angular JS.

http://austinknight.net/weather-app-with-angular-js/

Only limitation is this weather forecast for US only. I can find many API which provided world wide forecast but I can't connect with them the way author has done here.

```
$http.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20weather.forecast%20WHERE%20location%3D%22' + zip + '%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=')
```

Can someone please help me to write up such a query string based API call for any country ?

I have done sufficient research but couldn't find anything similar.

Please help.

Comment: Every such api provider will give you a URL. You just have to use that. Give some example URL so that we can help you build the query string

Comment: You are using yahoo weather API. The examples on that pages is sufficient for you to do what you wanted to. If you have issues understanding how it works, that is a different thing not as you have stated in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass params like this

```
$http.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql', {
      params: {
      q: 'your query',
      format: 'json',
      diagnostics: true,
      callback: ''
     }
});
```

Comment: Yeah Look at this place (https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) for more information about the API endpoints

Comment: I just told how to send a get request with params and not how to use yahoo api